# How to change the viewer preferences in a PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

[The PDF standard](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) states that it should be possible to set 'viewer preferences' in a PDF, which allows you to preset how a user will see the document.

Are there any free command line tools or fully open sourced libraries (so not restricted / licensed libraries like iText) that can be used to do this? All I found was BeCyPDFMetaEdit, which is a Windows tool.

Comment: You can write either a small Java or a small C# program using iText or iTextSharp to change the viewer preferences.

Comment: Thanks, but surely that must have been done before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with the [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.020/lib/PDF/API2.pm) Perl package (which is free):

```perl
use PDF::API2;

$pdf = PDF::API2->open("old.pdf");

$pdf->preferences(
        -centerwindow => 1,
        -fitwindow => 1,
        -hidetoolbar => 1,
        -hidemenubar => 1,
        );

$pdf->saveas('new.pdf');
```

Comment: awesome - thanks a bunch! points are yours, but i need to find a way to move them cause I accidentally awarded them to the wrong answer. Page scrolling is a b#$&1

Comment: What wrong answer? To me it looks like the bounty wasn't awarded at all.

Comment: it was awarded, but the answer got deleted - i think this was because I flagged the question and reported that I wanted to move the bounty to you. You can see that my rep has lost points in my history...

Comment: @user1914292 I deleted my answer because I don't want to receive a [mistakenly awarded] bounty from you.

Comment: thanks - but i still lost the bounty :) i think we found a glitch here

Comment: The bounty FAQ says that awarded bounties cannot be undone (http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties). See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177531/how-can-i-undo-my-bounty, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140290/bounty-awarded-to-a-different-answer-by-mistake (+25, unanswered!).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not getting an answer to this question, because it's not a real question in the context of the [FAQ on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). A question on SO should be about a technical issue you've encountered while trying something. Asking *"Can you give me a sample?"* isn't always accepted. You risk getting a counter-question: *"What have you tried?"*

This being said, in response to your comment: *"Surely this must have been done before?"*: of course, it has! I didn't answer right away because I didn't have the time, and also because the answer to your question is a no-brainer. I assumed you'd find the answer yourself without any problem.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("test.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("test_changed.pdf"));
stamper.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.CenterWindow | PdfWriter.FitWindow);
stamper.addViewerPreference(PdfName.PRINTSCALING, PdfName.NONE);
stamper.addViewerPreference(PdfName.NUMCOPIES, new PdfNumber(3));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

You take an existing PDF with `PdfReader`, you copy it to a changed PDF with `PdfStamper`. In-between you can use either the [`setViewerPreferences()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/interfaces/PdfViewerPreferences.html#setViewerPreferences%28int%29) method or the [`addViewerPreference()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/interfaces/PdfViewerPreferences.html#addViewerPreference%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfObject%29) method. If you follow the links provided for these methods, you'll get an overview of the possible viewer preferences.

This is an iText (Java) example; changing it into an iTextSharp (C#) example is a matter of changing some lower cases into upper cases here and there.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the CEO of iText Software. I'm also the original developer of iText and the author of the "iText in Action" books.

Comment: sorry, my question was not clear enough. I did search the web quite thoroughly but only found PAID products or a Windows product. No command line tools and no fully open sourced libraries. Whilst your answer helps, it's bound by a different license than the one I'm looking for. The reason the bounty's there, is because the question got so little attention - not because (IMHO) I didn't search the web like crazy...

Comment: In that case, you may clarify your question by adding that you're looking for a free lunch. That will avoid people like me wasting precious time ;-)

Comment: even though your product is great, in all fairness - stackoverflow is meant for more than just promoting your product...

Comment: AWESOME. Thank you!